# Rails Whenever gem run only one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, resque, whenever

I am using Whenever gem to setup a schedule. I added Whenever to `gemfile` and created `schedule.rb` file with code as below:

```
every 1.minute do
  p "testing ......................" 
end
```

I run the command `whenever` and the message `testing ......................` appears only once.

I need to put the message once per minute. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to top of your `schedule.rb` which basically creates a log file in your_app_path/log/cron_log.log

```
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
```

You can check the log file to monitor the cron job output.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variable as true and check true condition for that variable under scheduler.rb,make it false after first run.

Hope this will work for you !